# How to make highcharts display date in hh:mm:ss format, not as timestamp?

Tags: highcharts, angular7, date-formatting

I need to display xAsis labels as hh:mm:ss time format, but highcharts is displaying labels as timestamp it's getting from BE.

I've tried setting format to xAsis object like this:

```
   xAsis: {
        type: "datetime",
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            second: "%H:%M:%S"
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return (new Date(this.value).toLocaleTimeString();
            }
        }
```

It should have shown time as 11:30:23, but it still shows label as timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo - instead of `xAsis` there should be `xAxis`:

```
xAxis: {
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pa7516c0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis